# How do I remove the gap between the two rows of images?

Tags: css

I managed to get the gaps in left and right away, with font-size property, but I can’t seem to get the gap in the middle away? Please help! I’ve got stuck on this

I’ve tried margins and padding and it does nothing - I don’t know what it is targeting !

```
     .container{
        font-size: 0;
        height: 100px;
        width: 135px;
     }
     a{
        position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        width: 45px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    a img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        opacity:1;
     }
    a .main-img{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    a .hover-img{
        opacity:0;
     }
    a:hover .main-img{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    a:hover .hover-img{
        opacity: 1;
    }![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MyN7.jpg)
```

Comment: Your height of the link has a height of 50px and a width of 45px try setting them equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the contents (`<img />`) of an element (`<a>`) with absolute positioning, that parent element (`<a>`) wont know the dimensions of it's children (`<img />`) so that's why you need to manually set the width and height of `<a>`. So the gap in this case is because the images are not in the proportion you set of `<a>` with `width=45px` and `height=50px`

There are many ways to approach this:

1. If you really want to keep it the way you are doing it (not recommended), you would need to set the `width` and `height` of `<a>` the same proportion as your images (and all images would need to have the same proportions). So for example if the images are perfect squares, make the `width` and `height` of `<a>` the same: https://jsfiddle.net/qr0zujf7/1/
2. Another way could be to just set `.img-hover` absolute and not `.main-img`, so that `.main-img` set the dimensions of `<a>`, in this way you don't need to worry about the dimensions of the `<a>` in case the images are not all the same proportions (except `.main-img` and `.hover-img`): https://jsfiddle.net/a6ymj4yc/2/

Btw, you don't need this `a:hover .main-img { opacity=0; }`

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly on jsfiddle, but on my machine, it’s showing one image per line, why would this be happening, when it works fine for you? (On jsfiddle I mean)

Comment: I mean the second one

Comment: Check the width of the `.container`, I’m using a bigger one than you because my row sums up 300px width for 3 images. Or can you replicate yours on jsfiddle?